# What is the best practice the ordering of non-crud methods in controllers

Tags: laravel, rest

Most of my controllers follow the basic RESTful resource controller methods described in the laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers. I have been ordering my methods accordingly. For example, my controllers look like:

```
public function index()
{
    // some code
}

public function create()
{
    // some code
}

public function store()
{
    // some code
}

public function show()
{
    // some code
}

public function edit()
{
    // some code
}

public function update()
{
    // some code
}

public function destroy()
{
    // some code
}
```

However, occasionally I have a method which is not one of the basic CRUD ones, such as download(), for example. In best practice, where should you put this non-CRUD method. I have seen it sometimes just at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordering is not required. You can add the method anywhere in the controller And you should add a route to that method:

e.g.

```
Route::get('photo/download', 'PhotoController@download');
Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController');
```

Comment: However, ordering is required for the route

Answer (score 0):

It is not specifically related with `Laravel`. It is actually **code practice** and **code organization**.

For you own methods other than `Restful crud` methods, I recommend to follow **Robert C. Martin** (**Uncle Bob**) approach of how to organize the code of **the class**.

In the book of **Clean Code** (strongly recommend to read for every programmers), **Uncle Bob** describes as follow

> Public functions should follow the list of variables. We like to put
>   the private utilities called by a public function right after the
>   public function itself. This follows the stepdown rule and helps the
>   program read like a newspaper article.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this